# Can MS Access Projects be run by different users on a Windows terminal-server simultaneously via RDP?

Tags: sql-server, terminal-server, microsoft-access

An existing **MS Access 2003 project frontend** with a **MS Sql Server 2005 backend** needs to be accessed from different locations (not just one LAN anymore). Instead of implementing a VPN, we are thinking about **moving the SQL Server as well as the MS Access project to a Windows 2008 terminal-server** (hosting outsourced).

Will it be possible for 20 users to access this server by RDP an run their individual instancea of MS Access without interference with the other users' instances? Would that be a good solution?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning how many simultaneous users are expected. That'll have a big effect on licencing and specification of the server.

Comment: The 20 will be accessing the server simultaneously. Of course the server needs to be strong enough, but this question is more about general feasability and potential interference problems.

Comment: Feasability wise then, yes it'll work. As far as Access is concerned it might as well be separate machines accessing a central server.

Comment: Keep in mind that deployment-wise for each user, it's no different than if they were running the app on individual workstations. That is, each user should have their own copy of the front end, even though the temptation would be to share a single front end on the Terminal Server -- don't do it. It's bound for grief. Tony Toews's front-end updater handles distribution of the front end quite well and is both WTS and Citrix-compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, that will work.

Not only can each user run their own instance of Access, they can each run multiple instances. Assuming of course that there are no limits on the backend SQL Server (I don't use it, so I don't know). I do the same thing here using Access as a front end to MySQL databases.